# Iterate through JSON from API for first True number? py2.7

Tags: python, json, api

I am pretty new to Python, and am more used to JS, so I am a little lost on how to do this.

Basically I have a JSON from an API from Google, and the first result isn't always valid for what I need. But I do only need to the first result that returns true.

I am pretty sure I have the syntax wrong in more than one area, but I need the first `imageUrl` where [gi]['pagemap'] would be true.

```
item_len = len(deserialized_output['items'])

for gi in range(item_len):
    def loop_tgi():
        if deserialized_output['items'][gi]['pagemap'] is True:
            imageUrl = deserialized_output['items'][gi]['pagemap']['cse_image'][0]['src']
            break
        loop_tgi()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over items directly, without a use of index

in Python loop leak a variable, so when you break from the loop, gi variable would have what you need (or last value).

To overcome "or last value" we can use else close to check that we went through whole loop with no break

```
for gi in deserialized_output['items']:
    if gi['pagemap'] is True:
        break
else:
    gi = None  # or throw some sort of exception when there is no good elements

if gi:  # checking that returned element is good
    print(gi)  # now we can use that element to do what you want!
    imageUrl = gi['pagemap']['cse_image'][0]['src']
```

I am a bit worried about your `gi['pagemap'] is True` as later you try to access `gi['pagemap']['cse_image']`. It means that `gi['pagemap']` is not a boolean, but some sort of object.

If this is dict, you could check `if gi['pagemap']:` that is True if this dict is not empty. but `gi['pagemap'] is True` would be `False` if `gi['pagemap']` is `{'cse_image':...}`